# SQL Full Text Search workaround for integer values

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm trying to make a full text search with multiple columns. It's not my problem. I have different relevances for the different columns. No problem so far.

At first I show you my table. It's easier to explain

```
ID | course_name | course_level | duration | place
--------------------------------------------------------
1  |math, physics|6             |3 months  |Spaichingen
2  |physics      |6             |4 months  |Spaichingen
3  |math         |7             |3 months  |Spaichingen
4  |physics      |7             |5 months  |Spaichingen
5  |math         |6             |3 months  |Trossingen
6  |physics      |6             |4 months  |Trossingen
7  |math         |7             |3 months  |Spaichingen
8  |math         |7             |5 months  |Spaichingen
```

If I am looking for the course Math 7 I could use the where-clause like following:

```
... WHERE course_level = '7'
```

With Match-Against I can search and filter for math. The place and if the course is a combination with other subjects doesn't matter. If you look for math 6 and physics 6 the first course (id = 1) has the highest score and so on.

How I calculate the score doesn't matter. The only problem I have is if I want to search for Math 7 and the duration should be 5 months the record 8 should have an higher score than the record 7. But the problem is that the full text search can't differ the text by number values. The word months are still the same. The duration score are the same.

Is there a solution which is better than using three months, four months, etc.?

Sorry for my bad english. It's only a simple example which shows the problem of the full text search. It's also possible that number values could be used in other situations.

Comment: Add Your expected output

Comment: show your expcted  result

Comment: With respect, your `course_name` shows evidence of the notorious database design antipattern called *denormalization*. You need a separate table for course names, with items like `math, physics` represented by two columns rather than a comma-separated value.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  Fix your data model!

Storing multiple values in a single column is not the proper way to use relational databases.  Instead, create a table with one row per course id and "topic" (which seems more appropriate than name:

```
create table course_topics (
    course_topic_id int auto_increment primary key,
    course_id int not null,
    topic varchar(255)
);
```

Then you can combine this with your unnamed table, which I will call `courses`:

```
select . . .
from courses c join
     course_topics ct
     on ct.course_id = c.id
where c.course_level = 7 and
      ct.topic = 'Math';
```

This query can take advantage of indexes and you don't need full text search.

Comment: I know you are right. It's only an easy example. It's not my problem. My problem is that I want to have different score for example on the different months.
If I am searching for 4 months the 4 months results should get a score, the 3 months or 5 months result shouldn't get a score.

The problem with full text search is that it can't give a score to numeric values. So 3 months, 4 months and 5 months are getting the same score because of the word months.